# How do you make the meteorjs reactive-froala editor update when its value changes?

Tags: javascript, meteor, froala

I'm using meteorjs and the [froala-reactive editor](https://github.com/froala/froala-reactive).

In my router I return the collection data to the template, which works fine.

But I need the ability to update the contents of editor. What is the best way to update `_value`?

The template code:

```
{{> froalaReactive _onbeforeSave=doSave inlineMode=false _value=getText}}
```

The router.js code:

```
Router.route('admin/pages/:_id', function () {
  this.render('Page', {
    data: function () { 
      Session.set('editorContent', 'editor content here');
      return Pages.findOne({_id: this.params._id}) 
  }});
});
```

Helper function:

```
Template.Page.helpers({
    getText: function () {
        var self = this;
        return function (e, editor, data) {
          return Session.get("editorContent");
        };
    }
});
```

I expect that when the session variable editorContent changes the displayed content in the editor updates, but this is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Your helper function should simply return the Session value, instead of a function.

Like this:

```
getText: function () {
    return Session.get('editorContent');
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://github.com/jrullmann/froala-reactive-example) that you can clone and play around with.

Comment: Just a heads-up, the working example link 404s for me.